# I am trying to import csv file into mysql, but I am getting below error. Can anyone help me?

Tags: mysql, cloudera

LOAD DATA INFILE ‘/home/cloudera/Desktop/Sql Data/Customer.csv’ replace INTO TABLE Customers FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' lines terminated by '\n';

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘/home/cloudera/Desktop/Customer.csv

Comment: perhpas try a path without space OR lines terminated in uppercase, after see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Comment: I see that you are using two different kinds of apostrophes  ‘ and  ' aren't the same which may cause the syntax error

Comment: Thank you,, you are right apostrophes are different.

Comment: I mentioned the same as an answer. Please mark it as solved.

Comment: :D I did it.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy parts of the query? Could it be that there is an encoding issue and your „’“ are different?

Transform the query into plain text and try again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cruxi .. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use '\' instead of '/'in your file's path.

Also try to read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)... hope it helps

Comment: changing slash doesn't work,,
but that link helped me. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/cloudera/Desktop/SqlData/Customer.csv' INTO TABLE Customers FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

It worked.